# How does this "&" work in this statement?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know how bitwise AND works,but I don't understand how does (sourceDragMask & NSDragOperationGeneric) work here,I  don't get the point.Is there anyone can explain to me?Thanks a lot.

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender
{
    NSPasteboard *pboard;
    NSDragOperation sourceDragMask;

    sourceDragMask = [sender draggingSourceOperationMask];
    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSColorPboardType] )
    {
        if (sourceDragMask & NSDragOperationGeneric)
        {
            return NSDragOperationGeneric;
        }
    }

    return NSDragOperationNone;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how bitwise AND works,but I don't understand how does (sourceDragMask & NSDragOperationGeneric) work here,I don't get the point.

`NSDragOperationGeneric` is most likely a power of two, which means it has only one bit set. This is deliberate: Bit masks are almost all defined as powers of two (single bits) to enable bit-mask operations like this one.

The bitwise-AND operation, as you know, evaluates to only those bits that are set in both sides. If one side has only one bit (`NSDragOperationGeneric`) set, then the operation effectively tests whether that bit is set in the other side.

That's the point of the operation: To test whether the `NSDragOperationGeneric` bit is set.

There is one gotcha: As you know, a successful bitwise AND test will evaluate to the tested-for bit mask, *not* 1. So, for example, if you test for a bit mask that's defined as 0x100 (1 followed by 8 clear bits), then assign that result to a `BOOL` (which is a `signed char`) variable, you'll assign zero to the variable! This is why you sometimes see code like this:

```
BOOL supportsCopyOperation = ((dragOperations & NSDragOperationCopy) == NSDragOperationCopy);
```

or this:

```
BOOL supportsCopyOperation = ((dragOperations & NSDragOperationCopy) != 0);
```

or this:

```
BOOL supportsCopyOperation = !!(dragOperations & NSDragOperationCopy);
```

Other bit-mask operations include bitwise-OR (`|`) to set bits in a value (`return NSDragOperationCopy | NSDragOperationMove;`, for example) and bitwise-NOT (`~`, a.k.a. two's complement) to invert the bits of a value, usually for “anything but” tests.

Answer (score 6):

`NSDragOperationGeneric` is a bit-mask — probably a power of two — meaning that only one bit in the number is set. A bit-wise `&` with `sourceDragMask` will produce a non-zero output if and only if the corresponding bit is set in `sourceDragMask`.

Hypothetically (I don't know the actual value of `NSDragOperationGeneric`):

```
sourceDragMask:         00011010
NSDragOperationGeneric: 00001000
a & b:                  00001000
```

In short, the if statement will succeed if `sourceDragMask` has the `NSDragOperationGeneric' bit set.

Answer (score 3):

`sourceDragMask` is what's called a bitmask: an integer that represents a a number of boolean flags. It's declared as a variable of type `NSDragOperation`, which is actually `typedef`ed from `NSUInteger`—it really is just that.

First off, the `&` operator is what's known as a "bitwise AND", which simply takes two numbers `AND`s each of the bits in them to create a new value. For example, `0011 1001 & 0101 1010 == 0001 0001`—`57 & 90 = 17`. Similarly, the `|` operator does a bitwise OR. Using these operators, we can use each of those 1s and 0s as a boolean flag separately.

So, if, for example, `sourceDragMask` is the value `12`, what does this tell us? In binary, `12` is represented as `0000 1100`, or `8 | 4`, which according to the [NSDraggingInfo Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDragOperation), is `NSDragOperationPrivate | NSDragOperationGeneric`. So if we `&` this with `NSDragOperationGeneric`, we get `4` out, which is non-zero and therefore true. In this way, we can check whether a bitmask contains a certain flag.